# Replace instances of \" with "

Tags: json, swift, string, replace, escaping

I am trying to strip out unwanted slashes from a json file. I can't simply replace all instances of \ but rather, i need to escape instances of \" with just "

e.g. my json string looks like so:

```
[{
    "type": "test",
    "action": "test",
    "filename": 1,
    "data": "{\"a\":1,\"b\":10000,\"c\":0,\"d\":\"\"}"
}, {
    "type": "test2",
    "action": "test2",
    "filename": 2,
    "data": "{\"a\":2,\"b\":10000,\"c\":15,\"d\":\"\"}"
}]
```

I can't figure out the syntax of a find and replace for this:

```
let jsonStringTrimmed = jsonString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: """)
```

Another possible pitfall is that the param d is a base64 encoded string so I need to be able to avoid replacing \" within the value for that key

The goal is to be able to use jsonStringTrimmed as below:

```
let jsonStr = try String(contentsOf: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
let jsonStringTrimmed = jsonStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\", with: """)
let json = try JSONSerializer.toDictionary(jsonStringTrimmed)
```

UPDATE:

I initially had tried:

```
 do {
     let jsonStr = try String(contentsOf: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

     let json = try JSONSerializer.toDictionary(jsonStr)
 }
 catch {
     print("Error reading file : \(error)")
 }
```

And I was getting into the catch and receiving the error jsonIsNotDictinary

UPDATE 2 : Trying to loop through array after employing NivraD's approach:

```
 if let jsonData = try? Data(contentsOf: path){
        if let array = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])) as? [[String: Any]] {
            for i in array{
                print(array[i]?["data"] as! String)
                let dataJsonStr = array[i]?["data"] as! String
                if let dataDict = try? JSONSerializer.toDictionary(dataJsonStr){
                    print("a : \(dataDict["a"] as! String)")
                }
            }
        }
        else{
                print("in the else of if let array")
        }
    }
    else{
        print("in the else of if let jsonData")
    }
```

but this gives me the error: 
Cannot subscript value of type [[String : Any]] with an index of type Dictionary pointing to:
print(employeeArray[i]?["data"] as! String)

Comment: You want value of a,b,c and d right?

Comment: @NiravD I need to replace the \'s so that I can convert the string to a json object for processing with JSONSerializer

Comment: try using `.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\\"", with: "\"")` since the `\` in a string is used to escape the next character

Comment: @milo526 Post as an answer? This is not a Swift question but one about regexps...

Comment: Tip: one should *never* mess with JSON strings manually. It's just *never* needed. If you find yourself in the need to do this it actually means you have another different issue. Instead, always use the proper serialization/deserialization methods as in Nirav's answer and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your String is `JSON` Array, so simply convert it to `Array` no need to replacing anything with it. So first get `Data` from `jsonString` and then use this `data` with `JSONSerialization` to get `Array` from it.

```
if let jsonData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    if let array = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])) as? [[String: Any]] {
        print(array.first?["a"])
    }
}
```

Comment: when trying your way exactly instead of using JSONSerializer lib, I still get into the else of if let dic =

Comment: What is `JSONSerializer.toDictionary` and `jsonStr` contains `"{\"a\":1,\"b\":10000,\"c\":0,\"d\":\"\"}"`, right?

Comment: jsonStr is the entire json posted in my q, not just the data key... JSONSerializer is available here: https://github.com/peheje/JsonSerializerSwift. I need to be able to access all key in the json not just the keys within the data key

Comment: @user2363025 Check my edited answer and get direct data using `Data(contentsOf:)`

Comment: still getting into the else of if let dic

Comment: Your response is Array so you need to use `[[String:Any]]` not `[String:Any]` check the edited answer.

Comment: great thanks, the only mistake is that "a" isn't available at the point where you are trying to access it, the keys available there are type, action etc.

Comment: @user2363025 because `data` key contains jsonString so you need to get that String and than convert it to data after that convert data to dictionary `[String:Any]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133000/discussion-between-user2363025-and-nirav-d).

Comment: @user2363025 `JSONSerialization.jsonObject` instead of  try? JSONSerializer.toDictionary with data

Comment: the issue isn't with JSONSerializer.toDictionary, the problem refers to the line above that: let dataJsonStr = array[i]?["data"] as! String and how my loop is structured

Comment: @user2363025 change that line to `let dataJsonStr = i["data"] as! String`.